# ZK ListBox Paging Button Size Issue

Tags: frameworks, listbox, paging, zk

Continuing with ZK studies, i had improved my knowledge about data binding and some .zul files components properties. So i read about properties of the Grids from here:

https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Data/Grid

My goal this time is to change the grid's paging button size (example of grid)

https://www.zkoss.org/_w/images/b/b9/ZKComRef_Grid_Paging.png

The document tells about paging, paginal properties and sorting but there is nothing about the property related with the buttons generated on the grid. Any suggestions about it? i'm glad to hear them out. Thanks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are things we need to solve with css.
I'll try to explain how we come to this, so you can css almost everything.
First of all, open your browser developertools and inspect the button element.

When you do that, you see what css class is added to that button.
In all 4 buttons we find the css class : `z-paging-button`

With this info we can adjust our css (in a css file or for fast local changes in a zul file with the `style` tag.)

```
<style>
    .z-paging-button {
        width:300px;
    }
</style>
```

Sometimes, it's possible the css won't take, just try adding `!important` in the css.
Some example where you need to do this is for black digits in an disabled datebox :

```
<datebox disabled="true" style="color:black !important;" />
```

Comment: Ok, i think i got it, i will test your solution, thank you very much chillworld!